# creating multiple transport connection on same java mail session

Tags: java, kotlin, jakarta-mail

These are my properties

```
val props = Properties()
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required",true);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.debug",true)
props.put("mail.smtp.quitwait", false)
```

My session object

```
val session = Session.getInstance(props)
```

My transport connection

```
val transport1= session.getTransport("smtp")
val transport2= session.getTransport("smtp")
```

I want to know that is above line of code creating two different transport connection with my mail server.
if yes then if I am able to send 10 mail per minute with transport connection transport1 then now I am able to send 20 mail per minute using both transport connection.Is I am correct.

In my project I am sending large no of email.For this I am using multiple instance of service which is sending email.Is it good to create separate transport connection for each instance or use same transport instance b/w all instance of service.

Comment: Have you considered comparing the `Transport` objects?

Comment: And what makes you think two connections will be faster than one? There's only one network.

Comment: I am thinking if we have multiple connection with server then we perform multiple operation at same time(parallel).

Answer (score 3):

Calling session.getTransport twice will create two Transport objects, each of which can have it's own connection to the server.  Whether that provides better performance depends on the multiprocessing/multithreading capabilities of both the client and the server, as well as the speed of the network.